# Hibernate Relationships Annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Using @ManyToOne and @OneToMany how do I define relationships between the following tables. I'm new to hibernate and am unsure if my work is correct. Do I need two separate relationship annotations for the two foreign keys in the route table?

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE BusStop ( 
ID int NOT NULL,
Description varchar(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Route ( 
Route_Number int NOT NULL,
Destination int NOT NULL
Frequency int NOT NULL,
Start int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Route_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Destination) 
REFERENCES BusStop(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Start) REFERENCES BusStop(ID) 
Engine=InnoDB
```

BusStop.java:

```
public class BusStop {

public static final String SELECT_ALL = "BusStop.selectAll";

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

public BusStop(){}
public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void setDescription( String description ) {
    this.description = description;
 }

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }

@OneToMany(mappedBy="startRef")
private Set<Route> startStop;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="destRef")
private Set<Route> destStop;

}
```

Route.java

```
@Table(name = "route")
public class Route {
public static final String SELECT_ALL = "Route.selectAll";

@Id
@Column(name = "route_number")
private int route_number;

@Column(name = "destination")
private int destination;

@Column(name = "frequency")
private int frequency;

@Column(name = "start")
private int start;

private Set<Operator> operators = new HashSet<Operator>();

public Route(){}

// getters & setters

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="start")
private BusStop startRef;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="destination")
private BusStop destRef;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Okay . Update Route to these to use the key. Note you have these values just correcting the column name

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private BusStop startRef;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private BusStop destRef;
```